# How dangerous are tailwind gusts for STOL aircraft?

Tags: safety, lift

If I  fly close to stall speed  with a STOL plane and gust of 20kts tailwind comes at me,it will cause sudden reduction in lift ,becuase plane has inertia so it can not accelerate instantly.

How dangerous is this situations?

Comment: Downvoted because your opening statement is incorrect. Wind is just a moving air mass. The aircraft (or seagull) flight through the air mass is not affected by how fast the air mass is moving.

Comment: It's only a problem when taking off. The rest of the time it's a plus.

Comment: Each time you have edited your question, you have actually made it worse. A car on a bridge has absolutely no commonality which an aircraft in flight.

Comment: Again your edit has further degraded your question. Ground speed has NOTHING to do with wind gusts or wind shear.

Comment: @JohnK Is headwind better for landing too? I think it is..

Comment: After many edits, your question has some validity. But now the previous answers also need to be edited to match your new question.

Comment: @MikeSowsun `some validity`????? Your problem is that you are stuck with constant wind speed and not give up.I know that you know what  my question is,but your intetion from begginig is to devalue my question.

Comment: @Aeolus I was referring to tailwind only.

Comment: @JohnK  `The rest of the time it's a plus`  But tailwind is not plus when landing?

Comment: When in the air I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the wind is constant, it doesn't matter. The aircraft move relative to the surrounding air, and doesn't care how the air moves relative to the ground. If the aircraft has an (true) airspeed of 100 knots, and a tailwind of 100 knots, it's flying 200 knots relative to the ground. If the aircraft turns into the wind it will stlil fly 100 knots relative to the air, but 0 knots with respect to the ground.

The danger comes with gusts. If the aircraft is flying 100 knots airspeed in a 10 knot tailwind, it is flying 110 knots relative to the ground. If there is a gust of wind increasing the tailwind to 50 knots in an instant, the groundspeed will still be 110 knots. The airspeed will thus suddenly drop to 60 knots. That's the kind of speed drop that can cause stalls and  crash aircraft.

Comment: Yes  constant wind dont exist,at least where I live..

Comment: @Aeolus That's because you live on the ground. Trees, buildings, etc. create a lot of turbulence, which you feel as changing wind. Up where airplanes fly, the wind is almost always pretty constant.

Comment: @Aeolus that trimaran crash was nowhere near 40 knots of wind. I guess it was 15 knots wind. Gusts are more difficult to assess, but I'd be surprised if there was more than 25 knots. Incredible how the didn't release the main sheet or steered upwind... probably a jammed sheet and then taken by surprise.

Comment: @DeltaLima I just say it can blown 40kts,for sure it was much less wind,yes very big mistake or maybe some failure..this second wsurf video is in Luderitz ,they sail at winds topping 65kts! and now wsurf has 3 year project to beat sailing record of 66kts useing cavitating fins/foils..

Comment: @Aeolus Part of any student pilot's primary flight training is navigation by dead reckoning. If I'm flying at 100kts, it should take me 30min to reach an airport 50nm away. But if I have a 50kt tailwind, then my ground speed will actually be 150kts, so I'll reach the airport in 20min. The winds aloft are steady enough that this was the primary navigation method before radio navaids were invented, and still serves as a useful backup.  Now, that's not to say that gusts that severe don't occasionally happen. But, unlike boats, planes aren't in contact with the water, so there's nothing to resist

Comment: the change beyond the plane's own inertia. So, as I mentioned in my own answer, there's a momentary gain/loss of lift, i.e. turbulence, then the plane adjusts to the new airspeed and keeps flying.

Comment: @HiddenWindshield `The winds aloft are steady enough that this was the primary navigation method before radio navaids were invented, and still serves as a useful backup` How pilot knows what  was wind speed and direction  before radio navigation  was inveted?

Answer (score 1):

No. Any airplane (big or small) flies relative to the air in which it is moving. So, if there's a 10 knot tailwind, the **air**speed of the plane will remain the same, while the **ground** speed is increased by 10 knots. And since ground speed doesn't affect lift, then there is no change in lift produced.

Having said that, there are two situations where the wind speed is relevant:

1. When the wind speed changes rapidly (called [wind shear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_shear)), the airplane's inertia keeps it from changing speed instantly. If the shear is very severe, this might lead to a momentary loss of lift, which the passengers will experience as slight turbulence.
2. During takeoff and landing, the airplane is actually touching the ground, therefore, ground speed suddenly becomes relevant. This is why airplanes always take off and land into the wind whenever possible, to get as much lift as possible at a lower ground speed.

Comment: Re passengers experiencing wind shear as "slight turbulence", note that it has been the cause of quite a number of crashes.